# What is the sign of the energy exerted by a man sitting in the back of a boat pulling a canoe?

Tags: forces, energy, work

A man sits on the back of a boat pulling a canoe while the boat travels at a constant velocity a certain distance in the positive X direction. The man feels a constant tension in the rope during this time.

Would the energy expended by the man be a negative value? The rope is pulling the man in the negative X direction, so it would seem to me that the work done by him would be a negative value.

Comment: If by energy, you mean work, it is only negative when displacement and force have some antiparallel components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of non-idealized things in your situation.

The boat's engine is burning fuel and exerting energy to keep the boat moving. Meanwhile, the canoe is acting as an energy sink (creating turbulence in the water). The man could just be replaced by a metal hook connecting a rope to the canoe.

So yes, negative work is being done on the boat, but it has nothing to do with the guy. It starts with an energy $E$ - the chemical potential energy of  the fuel - and $E$ decreases over time. If the engine were 100% efficient, and if there was no friction/turbulence on the boat (only on the canoe), then $E$ as a function of time would be $E-Tvt$ where $v$ is the velocity, $T$ is the tension, and $t$ is the time elapsed. The negative work is $-Tvt$ term. The energy of the boat+fuel system is going into heating up/creating turbulence in the water, through the canoe.

Answer (score 3):

The man does no work.  It's easy to see this by replacing the man with a bit of wood screwed to the boat and tying the rope to it: clearly you can pull the canoe for ever and the bit of wood is not somehow going to run out of energy.  Well, men are no different than bits of wood, so the man also does no work.

(Of course, in practice muscles are not very efficient (in fact are completely inefficient) when exerting a constant static pull, so the man may get tired: that's because, although he's not very different than a bit if wood he is, in this respect, not as good.)